# Program that helps you find the Meta of each key on your keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm sure my topic words are completely wrong.Meta can't be the right word.
I apologize.

Anyways I love using tiling window managers. Like Ratpoison or Spectrwm. But life intervened and kept me away from the computer and strictly to my phone for a few years.So I am very rusty to these window managers now. And openbox is great(Im sure someone would have brought that one up ;), but I like to have multiple managers to play with.

I used to use a program to find out what my Volume keys are, my media key, mute, and so on. I remember the particular program popped up two terminals I think? One would have you press the key, and the screen behind it would pop out the meta.Anyone know what I'm talking about, or something similar? I've searched multiple threads, but they're all members telling other members that Alt is Mod1, or Mod4 is Super. But I'm looking for a program to do this for me.

Thank you for reading and thank you for any responses.

Oh...and what's really weird, take spectrwm for example, Mod1+whatever will open the program I assigned to it, but then the very next Mod1+whatever won't open my other program I assigned it too. And it's not conflicting with another keybind.Which would think that's whats happening, but a quick search in the config file shows not one confliction.

tl;dr Looking for a program to tell me what the meta is for each key on my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

If understand your idea correctly, then on X11 session, the application is named Event Tester, the `xev` executable from `x11-utils` package.

Its output is usually the following:

> - for left <kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> key:
>   `KeyPress event, serial 83, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
>   root 0x134, subw 0x0, time 37174913, (-1,423), root:(0,507),
>   state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,`
> - for <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>TouchPad</kbd>:
>   `KeyPress event, serial 87, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
>   root 0x134, subw 0x0, time 37421164, (712,327), root:(713,411),
>   state 0x42, keycode 199 (keysym 0x1008ffa9, XF86TouchpadToggle), same_screen YES,`

It opens terminal and small window to track mouse/touchpad activity.

Getting the meaning of keyboard shortcuts for selected window manager depends on the window manager.